# Ubuntu migrated VM NIC not up on boot - CloudInit?

Tags: networking, cloud-init

I've just migrated my Reverse Proxy (Ubuntu 18.04/NGINX) VM from Hyper-V to ESX

All seems to work ok, except the new VM no longer uses `eth0` It has a new interface `ens160` from the new NIC

I've made a DHCP reservation for the MAC adress and I can make the interface come up manually:

```
sudo ifconfig ens160 up
sudo dhclient
```

However, on reboot, the interface is down until I do these commands - I can't find any how to enable on boot

I'm pretty sure it's using the CloudInit and have amended `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/50-curtin-networking.yaml` to include the new interface:

```
network:
    eth0:
      addresses: []
      dhcp4:true
      optional:true
    ens160:
      addresses: []
      dhcp4:true
```

Then restart and reboot

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

But still the interface is still down on reboot

I tried the same amending the config at `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`

Now the interface is up on reboot, but grabs an address before the DHCP-assigned one takes effect - I have to do this to get it on the DHGCP address:

```
sudo dhclient -r
sudo dhclient
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this turned out ridiculously easy in the end.

I was trialling out a Windows DHCP server on my network and the `dhcp-identifier` entry is required to use it.....

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp-identifier: mac
```